# Change icon BiometricPrompt android

Tags: java, android, biometrics

Is it possible to change icon fingerprint for BiometricPrompt (api level 28)?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: are you using the androidx `Biometric` library?

Comment: yes, I'use this library

Comment: You currently can't because the drawables are directly referenced in the fragment code as you can see here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/biometric/src/main/java/androidx/biometric/FingerprintDialogFragment.java#345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. In official way if we talk about new BiometricPrompt implementation in AndroidX (23+ API level).

In older versions you can create your own custom dialog for this.